# Can't write data into MS Access database with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, database-connection

I have already build a successful login form. But I want to have the opportunity to create a new account. I have two textboxes; one for username and one for password. Once the button is clicked, it needs to write this data to a MS Access 2002-2003 database file. But when I click the button I get the following error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

This is the code I am using:

```
    private void buttonRegistreren_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Gebruikers (Username, Password) values('" + textBoxUserregist.Text + "', '" + textBoxPassregist.Text + "')";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
```

Somebody knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Also do **not** store your passwords as a plain text. Read: [Best way to store password in database](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1054022/447156)

Comment: Thanx for the tip. Will look into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Password is a reserved keyword in MS-Access, you need to encapsulate it between square brackets

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Gebruikers (Username, [Password]) ...."
```

said that please remember that string concatenations to build sql command is a very bad practice and leads to numerous problems. Start using parameters as soon as possible as in the example below

```
private void buttonRegistreren_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(.....))
    using(OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO Gebruikers
                    (Username, [Password]) values(@name, @pwd)", cn))
    {
        cn.Open();
        command.Parameters.Add("@name", OleDbType.NVarWChar).Value =textBoxUserregist.Text ;
        command.Parameters.Add("@pwd", OleDbType.NVarWChar).Value = textBoxPassregist.Text;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are the man! Thank you!